# Problem to current security

Tags: security

I have install ubuntu in my lap . But after restarting my lap there is a message that " ubuntu has blocked by current securty policy" what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/472867/windows-boot-manager-blocked-by-current-security-policy-for-lenovo-u-510 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/338014/ubuntu-blocked-by-current-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

The notice is: `HDD: has been blocked by the current security policy`?

See [step 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) on our help.ubuntu.com related to UEFI:

> In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.